# I have got this warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;

Tags: java, hibernate, variadic-functions

The Warning is :

> cast to java.lang.Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning

I am getting the warning in this line:

```
  l=(List)getHibernateTemplate().find(query,arr);
```

Here is the complete code:

```
public Boolean checkLogin(Utilisateur utilisateur) throws Exception
{
    Boolean f=false;
    try{
        List l=null;
        String query ="*from utlisateur where login=log and password=log";
        String [] arr=new String[2];
        arr[0]= utilisateur.getLogin();
        arr[1]= utilisateur.getPassword();
        l=(List)getHibernateTemplate().find(query,arr);
        if(l!=null){
            if(l.size()==1){
            f=true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        throw new Exception("Error from DAO " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return f;
}
```

How can I avoid this warning?

Comment: I think it should be: `(List)getHibernateTemplate().find(query,utilisateur.getLogin(), utilisateur.getPassword());`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring's [`HibernateTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html), the method supports vararg parameters. You should change your call like this:

```
 l = (List) getHibernateTemplate().find(
     query, utilisateur.getLogin(), utilisateur.getPassword());
```

**Reference:**

- Java Tutorial: [Arbitrary Number of Arguments](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html#varargs)
- Java Language Guide: [Varargs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html)